# Node.JS and Java PUB/SUB

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, zeromq, data-stream

I'm trying to build an application that the communication will be done by a `node.js` server. This node server will receive messages from others peers.

My `node.js` code is:

```
var zmq = require('zmq'),
    socket = zmq.socket('sub');

socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5556', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
        throw err;
    }

    socket.on('message', function (envelope, blank, data) {
        console.log(arguments);
    });

    socket.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(arguments);
    });
});
```

In the other part of the system, there is a `java` server that should send messages for this server.
This is my `java` code:

```
Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
Socket publisher = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB);
publisher.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");
for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr < 10; request_nbr++) {
    publisher.send("Hello");
}
```

For now, my `java` server is running locally and my `node.js` is running inside a docker with the port 5556 exposed.
I have success sending messages from the `java` server. But no message is received in my `node.js` server.

There is any problem in my ZeroMQ initialization?

Comment: There are some simple things you can do here to triage the problem - e.g. running outside of Docker, creating a Java subscriber, creating a Node publisher...

Comment: Running outside the docker doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, there is a problem:

As defined in the ZeroMQ protocol-specifications, the **SUB**-Formal Scalable Communication Pattern archetype has an empty subscription list upon it's instantiation.

### Empty SUB-side subscription is the cause:

Your SUB-side has to indeed subscribe to anything else ( be it at least a **`""`** - yes - an empty string is enough, for starting receiving any and all messages, or may setup some problem/context-specific string(s), as TOPIC-filter, where each message will start to get tested for a presence of at least one of such TOPIC-s, and discarded ( not `.recv()`-ed or not promoted into the hands of `.on( 'message', ... )` handler at all ).

Anyway, **enjoy the ZeroMQ powers** for the distributed computing!